# Couldn't install microsoft.net.4.8.KB50003304

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and coding in general, I tried installing VS 2022 and this error keeps popping up, please can someone lend me a hand.
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp4az.png)

Comment: Click on the *More troubleshooting tips* link in the lower left. There's nothing anyone here can do based on the information in that image.

Comment: [Some other people](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8&ftype=problem&preview2=true&q=Microsoft.Net.4.8.KB5003304) with this problem.  They need more info.